# I want to replace multiple strings with blanks in a single replace function

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to replace string with blank. For below script it works but when I have multiple string with different strings to replacce it with blanks I am getting stucked.

for example: ( I am getting list of string using xpath etxtract, for that suppose 8 strings are same, 3 strings are same, 2 strings are same,......)

```
links = [ 'ABCDEFGH google', 'ABCDEFGH google', 'Samsung mobile',  
'ABCDEFGH serachgoogle google', 'ABCDEFGH google',  'XYZacbxf 
12153131' , 'Samsung mobile', 'Apple smartphone x10',.............]

m = []
for link in links:
    temp = link.replace("ABCD", '')
    m.append(temp)
```

(In above first i am replacing 'ABCD'  with blank, and seond I want to replace 'ABCD'  with blank,  third i want to replace "mobile" with blank, upto 20+ difference strings with blanks in a single replce function)
(I don't know is it possible or not!, Someone have idea about this  please help.)
(Thanks in advance!)

Have tried=>

```
m = []
for link in links:
    temp = link.replace("ABCD", '' or "mobile", '' or "google", 
'' or ...........upto available replacing string) 
    m.append(temp)
```

Comment: What should be your final output?

Comment: output will be string without replacing strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a regex which will match all the terms you want to replace:

```
import re

links = ['ABCDEFGH google', 'ABCDEFGH google', 'Samsung mobile',  
'ABCDEFGH serachgoogle google', 'ABCDEFGH google',  'XYZacbxf',
'12153131' , 'Samsung mobile', 'Apple smartphone x10']

to_replace = ['ABCD', 'mobile', 'google']
regex = re.compile('|'.join(to_replace))

new_links = [re.sub(regex, '', link) for link in links]
print(new_links)
```

Output:

```
['EFGH ', 'EFGH ', 'Samsung ', 'EFGH serach ', 'EFGH ', 'XYZacbxf', '12153131', 'Samsung ', 'Apple smartphone x10']
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using an additional list, you can use regex to replace unnecessary strings from each element of list.

The regex looks like:

```
re.sub(r'ABCD|mobile', '', x)
```

**Code**:

```
import re

links = [ 'ABCDEFGH google', 'ABCDEFGH google', 'Samsung mobile',  'ABCDEFGH serachgoogle google', 'ABCDEFGH google',  'XYZacbxf 12153131' , 'Samsung mobile', 'Apple smartphone x10']

res = []
for x in links:
    res.append(re.sub(r'ABCD|mobile', '', x))

print(res)
# ['EFGH google', 'EFGH google', 'Samsung ', 'EFGH serachgoogle google', 'EFGH google', 'XYZacbxf 12153131', 'Samsung ', 'Apple smartphone x10']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way by also iterating over the strings to replace:

```
to_replace_terms = ['ABCD', 'mobile', 'google']
m = []
for link in links:
    for to_replace_term in to_replace_terms:
        link = link.replace(to_replace_term, '')
    m.append(link)
```

Note that you need to assign the replacement back to `link` since multiple replacements might happen.